# How to assign values from array via forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I've created a simple array from which I would like to assign the values of each row to attributes via generated HTML. I'm using a forEach and am exporting the values via variables but currently the only values being exported are the ones in the last row of the array. I understand why this is happening because the forEach is reaching the end and then simply exporting the last assigned values but I am unsure how to fix it.

At the moment the target forEach is working correctly and assigning a number for each of the div items being generated but the itemNumber and itemColour variable values are not being applied as expected.

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('div');
let targetCount = 0;

const items = [
    ['123456', 'Red'],
    ['234567', 'Blue'],
    ['345678', 'Yellow'],
]

// console.log(`Array size: ${targets.length}`);

targets.forEach((target, i) => {
    // console.log("i" + i);
    // console.log("targetCount " + targetCount);
    // console.log(items.length);


    if (i < items.length) {
        // console.log(`item: ${item}`);
        //target = target.closest(('.content-template'));

        let itemNumber;
        let itemColour;

        // loop through each item
        items.forEach(item => {
                itemNumber = item[0];
                itemColour = item[1];
                console.log(itemNumber);
                console.log(itemColour);
        });

        target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div id="${targetCount}" data-number="${itemNumber}" data-colour="${itemColour}">+</div>`);

        targetCount++;

    }
});
```

Full demo here: https://codepen.io/Shoxt3r/pen/eYMjbxP

Answer (score 0):

Move code that you want to run in a loop into the loop

```
items.forEach(item => {
  itemNumber = item[0];
  itemColour = item[1];
  console.log(itemNumber);
  console.log(itemColour);
  target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div id="${targetCount}" data-number="${itemNumber}" data-colour="${itemColour}">+</div>`);
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that the item gets generated according to the same number of times the forEach is called (5)?

Comment: I thought that is what you want.

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear - I would like the HTML to be injected into the available target items (in this case, the 3 divs). I would also like to pass both the itemNumber and itemColour into the generated divs, making sure to match the first div item with the first row of data in the array and so on.

EDIT: In fact, after reviewing a fork, I can see that the div injection is being called 3 times, 1 for each item in the array.

Comment: Ok so I had a look at creating a 1D array example and then decided to build upon that to create a 2D version and I think this should work well for my needs. Is this the best way to do it?

https://codepen.io/Shoxt3r/pen/QWmBPRa